# Can anyone explain the meaning of Ramraksha strotra?

Tags: rama

I heard that to maximize the effect of chanting *Ramraksha strotra*, I need to understand the Hindi meaning of it. Does anyone know the meaning of it fully? I don't know to read Hindi, but I understand. So writing Hindi with English alphabets is ok for me. Please share if anyone knows. The problem with other sources on the internet is, all are either written in Hindi or in English with translated meaning.

Here is a link of the strotra - https://www.voidcan.org/ramraksha-stotra/

Comment: Rama Raksha Stotra is Sanskrit Stotra. By Hindi meaning, you mean you want transliteration of Devanagari or meaning in Hindi language?

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_Raksha_Stotra

Comment: @TheDestroyer I mean translation of meaning from Devanagari to Hindi and as I don't know to read Hindi (but understand it, actually I am from Bengali region), if the alphabets of English are used that will be best for me. Like "Main India se hun".

Comment: @TheDestroyer I have checked that link, where the meanings are in English, not in Hindi. As in the middle coloumn of the table in the link, the sanskrit is written using the English alphabets, I need Hindi meaning with English alphabates. Actually, some of my family members know English alphabates but don't know much English. So, they can't understand if the meaning is written in English.

Comment: You can check Sanskrit documents site. It has stotras and scriptures in various scripts including Bengali. https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_raama/rraksha.html?lang=bn

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thank you very much sir :) But the meaning is not there.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Asking for Sanskrit translations is off-topic for the site because this site is not meant for translating Sanskrit into Hindi or English.We do not have Sanskrit experts here. You may find Hindi translations on the internet.

Comment: Do you need [meaning](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sri_Rama_Raksha_Stotram) or transliteration? Check word to word meaning at [sanskritdocuments.org](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_raama/ramarakmean.html?lang=sa).